# how to disable constraint in sybase

Tags: sybase, sap-ase

What is the syntax to enable/disable the constraint? I tried google 
in oracle I write it like this 
alter table  OPT DISABLE constraint  FK_param
how to do that in sybase?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply can't disable foreign keys constraints in sybase. But you can drop and recreate
them.

Drop constraint:

```
alter table table_name drop constraint constraint_name
```

Add constraint:

```
alter table table_name add constraint constraint_name
```

I know that in other DB's, there is something like a CHECK and NOCHECK on these constraints. So you could just NOCHECK the constraint you want to disable.

```
ALTER TABLE a1 NOCHECK CONSTRAINT a1_TestConstraint
```

Comment: shouse writing this query on sybase would work ? ALTER TABLE a1 NOCHECK CONSTRAINT a1_TestConstraint

Comment: @Moudiz , you can give it a try ;) I think I also read it somewhere on a sybase forum, so I think it will do the job.

Answer (score 0):

You can't disable constraints in sybase. You can drop/add constraints only.